# How can I calculate $Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, wienerprocess

How can I calculate? 
\begin{align}
Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)
\end{align}

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know that $E\left[\int_{0}^{s}W_udu\right]=E\left[\int_{0}^{t}W_vdv\right]=0$. By definition 
\begin{align}
& Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=E\left[\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right]-0
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
& Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}E\,[W_uW_v]\,\,du\,dv
\end{align}
Since $E\,[W_uW_v]=min \{\,u\,,v \}$ therefor
\begin{align}
& Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv
\end{align}
For the case $s<t$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{s}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv+\int_{0}^{s}\int_{s}^{t}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv
\end{align}
we immediately have
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{3}s^3+\frac{1}{2}(t-s)s^2
\end{align}
Following the same steps as described above, for the case $s > t$ we can also
 show
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{1}{2}(s-t)s^2
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
Cov\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\frac{1}{3}min\{s^3\,\,,t^3\}+\frac{1}{2}|t-s|min\{s^2\,\,,t^2\}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Can you explain why is $\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}E\,[W_uW_v]\,\,du\,dv=E\left[\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right]$?

Comment: Fubini's theorem